# How to interpret and call functions with an enum

Tags: c

Hello this particular function is definied as

```
void initBoard(Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH]);
```

and the `Cell` enum code is;

```
typedef enum cell
{
   BLANK, RED, CYAN
} Cell;
```

I was wondering how to interpret and then call this function, if I dissect the function to my best ability I know that;

`void` means that it doesn't return a value, 
`initBoard` is the name of the function, `Cell` is a enum (I don't know what this does or what to change this to when calling the function) and then `board[][]` would be making a 2d array for the function to use. If any one would be willing to give me a hand on how to call this function it would be great, thanks :)

Comment: Your title is misleading. There is no constructor in C.

Comment: @Gerhardh Changed it, thought it was a constructor my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the 2d array like:

```
Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
```

`board` is a 2D array (`BOARD_HEIGHT` x `BOARD_WIDTH`) where each value is a `Cell` (i.e. either `BLANK`, `RED` or `CYAN`).

To call your `initBoard()` function do:

```
initBoard(board);
```

Comment: When i call the function with this code; initBoard(BLANK board[3][3]); it returns an error saying that "error: expected ')' before 'board'" and once again im not sure how to fix it

Comment: @Kripzy Call like `initBoard(board);`